# How to combine multiple worksheets into one, with one key column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to combine three worksheets into one, with a key column. Each worksheet has the names of people in the first column, followed by columns of data and information related to the person, each sheet has different data or information on the person. So I want a sheet with names in the first columns followed by the columns of all the three sheets related to that person.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What have you tried already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried consolidating multiple ranges into a pivot table, and I've tried vLookup. The major issue in the different methods I've tried is that my sheets don't have a similar specific structure.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It would also help if you [edit] your question to include examples of the 3 tables as well as what you have already tried.

Comment: Honestly, I'd do an `index(match())` on the main one to the other two, then copy/paste values, if I were you. If I were me, I'd write VBA. Or put it in database and join on the key.